# Point Arvixe Domain to GoDaddy Hosting

Tags: wordpress, dns

I have a domain in Arvixe and I want to point it to my Wordpress website hosted in Goddady. 
I've tried to add that domain in my wordpress website and add the NS registers on Arvixe domain manager, but I found this error: `Registry error, domain's nameservers not updated [Object status prohibits operation]`

These are my DNS Register on Goddady:[image]
And this is my domain area on Arvixe:[image]

Did someone face this situation?

Comment: do you mean you want to point `www.yourdomain.bleh` at your wordpress site hosted on GoDaddy? or are you trying to move your dns to GoDaddy as well?

Comment: Yes, but when I try to do that on Arvixe Domain Manager, I got an error.

Comment: ok. - if you just want www then see my answer below - you are trying to move the ns records & it looks like the dns host won't allow that. you just need another entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to ask on Arvixe Support to point my domain to GoDaddy. So I informed the Register A and the Name Server to the attendant and he changed for me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to change the name servers or delegate your domain to GoDaddy when what you actually want is to point `www.yourdomain.bleh` at your Word Press site *hosted* on GoDaddy.

In the Arvixe domain manager simply add a `A` record pointing to the IP address of your GoDaddy web server and make sure the site is configured on GoDaddy as `www.yourdomain.bleh`

Unless you want to move the control of the DNS to GoDaddy then you don't need to worry about the dns settings at all on that side of things.

The error you get from your dns provider hints that they may not let you change the NS entries freely. (May they charge or require further checks in place before its allowed)

Comment: I tried like you said, but I still was having error, so I asked to the Arvixe Support like I said in the answer below. Thanks for your help.

Comment: no problem - glad you got it sorted and thanks for the upvote